# iredmail Dovecot Unknown protocol: sieve

Tags: apache, email, ssl, centos, postfix-mta

I'm using iredmail and my email client times out when trying to access the server. The error in the dovecot log is

```
  Dec 02 03:10:03 pop3-login: Fatal: Can't load CA file /var/lib/dkim/MYDOMAIN.com.pem: No such file or directory
```

dovecot -n shows:

```
doveconf: Error: protocols: Unknown protocol: sieve
doveconf: Error: SSL support not compiled in but ssl=yes
doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf: protocols: Unknown protocol: sieve
```

This was working fine until I made some PCI compliance changes, including disabling weak ciphers. Also I added php prepend script. I don't think iredmail relies on this as I only saw python scripts.

I read some other forums and they reinstalled pigeonhole, but I'm trying to avoid this as I installed through iredmail which requires a clean install without apache, mysql, dovecot, postfix, ldap, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came down to using a dovecot 1 conf file with dovecot 2. Instead of uninstalling everything on my server and reinstalling iredmail, I went with email from google apps.